# Synonym for Vim's normal mode CTRL-A?

Tags: vim

I came to an idea that `<C-a>` in Vim's normal mode should not only increase numbers but toggle booleans. It makes sense if you consider `true` and `false` as integers modulo 2.

So, I [downloaded an excellent script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1676) to do the hairy work and wrote a new definition for `<C-a>`:

```
fun! NewCA()
    let cw = tolower(expand("<cword>"))
    if cw == "true" || cw == "false"
        ToggleWord
    else
        " run the built-in <C-a>
        execute "normal \<C-a>"
    endif
endfun
command! NewCA :call NewCA()
nnoremap <C-a> :NewCA<cr>
```

But as it happens, `nnoremap` doesn't go as far as to check inside functions. I get recursive behaviour *if* my cursor is not on words `true` or `false`.

In this point I swear a lot, why didn't Bram go pick an excellent idea from Emacs, that everything should be functions and key bindings freely setable. Then I just could check the function for `<C-a>` and call it in that function. But no, I can't find such a function, and the `execute "normal foo"` phrases seem to be the Vim idiom.

Any suggestions on how I could make `<C-a>` work such that

- Toggle booleans when the cursor is over a word  `true` or `false`
- Fall back to built-in `<C-a>` behaviour otherwise

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change

```
execute "normal \<C-a>"
```

to:

```
normal! ^A
```

you can get ^A by running

```
<C-v><C-a>
```

in normal mode

the "!" at the end of normal say "use default mapping"

Comment: Both answers have the same, correct solution. I checked this as the accepted answer just to welcome you to the community. :)

Answer (score 6):

From `:help :normal`

```
:norm[al][!] {commands}     
...
If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.
....
```

Also defining a command is not needed, you can directly

```
nnoremap <C-a> :call NewCA()
```

Comment: Oh my, I feel such a noob! I should have known better .. to read the docs more carefully. Thanks greatly. In fact I had the extraneous `command!`  statement for debugging purposes, and you are right. :)

Comment: note the map needs a final `<cr>`  like: `nnoremap <C-a> :call NewCA()<cr>`