# Move to top of screen without H

Tags: vim

I normally have `H` mapped to `^` to make my navigation in the same line a little easier.

However, I just encountered a plugin (enhancement to EasyMotion) that uses H to move the cursor to the top of the screen before it searches. The plugin seems useful but obviously with my `H` mapping it won't work very well.

Can you think of another way to move the cursor to the top of the screen within a function? Basically, replicate the behavior of H without using H.

Comment: Top of the file or top of the screen? In case of top-of-the file, `1-G`

Comment: @Qiau Yeah I can think of a dozen ways to move to the top of the file. I need to move to the top of the screen

Comment: Maybe there is a way to figure out the line number of the top line and move it there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way is to submit a bug report or a patch to the enhancement's author. One should always take care to run commands with a `:normal!` with a bang when writing scripts for public consumption. That way any mappings on top of the builtin are ignored and consistent behaviour across configurations is better secured.

I once dabbled with the problem myself: [Synonym for Vim's normal mode CTRL-A?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4837349/308668)

And in clear writing: use `:normal!` instead of `:normal` in your scripts to ignore any user mappings.

Comment: It sounds like the answer is then `:normal!H`

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize that's what that `!` operator did. Just to clarify, it isn't the EasyMotion plugin but a custom function that enhances it. I changed it to `normal! H` instead of `normal H` and all is good. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Max: yes, `:normal! H` would do in your own scripts.

Comment: @mattedgod: Yeah, I just edited my miswriting. :) You should notify the author anyway. The world could use more robust vim scripts.

Comment: @progo Agreed! He/she has been notified